# PowerTOP issue with fresh 16.04 install on ThinkPad E555

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad, powertop

Here's what happened when I tried to set optimum settings after installing PowerTOP:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Dependency tree.
Status information can be read .... Done
Suggested packages:
  cpufrequtils laptop-mode-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  powertop
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get to archives 164 kB.
After this operation, 537 kB disk space will be used.
Get 1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial / main amd64 amd64 powertop 2.8-1build1 [164 kB]
164 kB downloaded in 0s (276 kB / s).
Selecting previously unselected package powertop.
(Reading database ... 175728 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to decompress ... / ... powertop_2.8-1build1_amd64.deb
Unpacking powertop (2.8-1build1) ...
Triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) are processed ...
powertop (2.8-1build1) is established ...
arno arno @ ThinkPad E555: ~ $ sudo powertop --auto-tune
not /var/cache/powertop/saved_results.powertop Load from file possible
not /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop Load from file possible
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement (s) with battery only
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL device for cpu 0
Devfreq not enabled
not /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop Load from file possible
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement (s) with battery only
  unknown op '{'
PowerTOP is terminated
```

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powertop/+bug/1588747

Answer (score 2):

True, at the moment PowerTop does not start when launched with --auto-tune options, but it actually applies the optimal settings... relaunch it with just `sudo powertop` and you'll see the difference.
Cheers